# In-game timer for pygame

Tags: pygame

I'm making a game for a school project and can not, for the life of me, figure out how to make an in-game timer to place in the upper right side corner. I wish for it to be sixty seconds long. I can find no syntax for this at all. Help please?

Comment: U havn't done any thing yet?

Comment: Not really. I have a label set for the timer but cannot figure this out at all.

Comment: Three answers have been posted...I anyone has helped you reaching your goal then please accept it as it helps others with same problem and also avoids asking of duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

At the beggining of your while (I assume you are using one with pygame) do this

```
start = get_ticks()
```

then at the end of your while (right before the drawing commands) do this

```
end = get_ticks() -start
if (end > 1000 /30)
    wait(end)
```

With this your game will run at 30/second, which means that your while will run 30 times a second, you can make a timer from there

if you need extra help just take a variable inside the while do this:

```
value += 1
```

Then to get timer do this:

```
print(value /30)
```

if you get lost at any step tell me!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to this link [Beginning Game Programming for Teens with Python](http://www.raywenderlich.com/24252/beginning-game-programming-for-teens-with-python) and look for how it works the whole code.

In that code you will find a similar part like this:

```
# 6.4 - Draw clock
font = pygame.font.Font("JUICE___.TTF", 44)
survivedtext = font.render(str((90000-pygame.time.get_ticks())/60000)+":"+str((90000-pygame.time.get_ticks())/1000%60).zfill(2), True, WHITE)
textRect = survivedtext.get_rect()
textRect.topright=[635,5]
screen.blit(survivedtext, textRect)
```

What you're looking for is the way in which works, so you must study the code and figure out for yourself :P

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do the same thing for a project of mine. Before you start your main loop define a font, a clock, and a set time the user has left

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Terminal", 20)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
time_left = 60.0
```

now in your main loop you want to call the clock.tick method and use it to subtract the time left on the clock

```
while True:
    time_passed = clock.tick()
    time_passed_seconds = time_passed/1000. #This is so we can set time_left to seconds and not have to use milliseconds
    time_left-=time_passed_seconds
```

Then when you get down to where you are drawing everything you can put in this

```
time_left_rendered = font.render("Time left = {:02}:{:02}".format(int(time_left)/60, int(time_left)%60), False, (255,255,255))
screen.blit(time_left_rendered, (0,0)) #or wherever you want it
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records and for everybody having this issue again:

The way jenko_cp described it is just lacking the crucial int() method:

```
font = pygame.font.Font("JUICE___.TTF", 44)
survivedtext = font.render(str(int((90000-pygame.time.get_ticks())/60000))+":"+str(int((90000-pygame.time.get_ticks())/1000%60)).zfill(2) ,1, black)
textRect = survivedtext.get_rect()
textRect.topright=[635,5]
screen.blit(survivedtext, textRect)
```

It´s actually quite smooth this way. The code counts down from 1:30 (and will repeat minutes forever thereafter). If you want more time, just change the 90000 to any multiple of 60000.